# logout api error - Rest Spring Security Plugin in Grails

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security

I have integrated REST Spring Security plugin in a Grails app. Login works fine, and returns the correct access token. I can call other actions with this Authentication Token in X-Auth-Token in header.

I'm using Grails 2.4.4, and spring-security-rest plugin 1.4.0 with JDK 1.6.

However, the logout isn't working and throws Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not
obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current
thread  at
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.getSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:210)
```

I have tried to upgrade to 1.4.1, 1.5.0 but they seem to be dependent on JDK 1.7 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue: https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/issues/135

It was fixed in the `1.4.1` release. You will have to upgrade to that version.

Comment: i tried to upgrade to that version but then it starts throwing ```unable to resolve class java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets```, so basically asking to upgrade java to 7 version... tough i am on java 6

Comment: You should upgrade - both Java 6 and Java 7 are at end-of-life.